# php:how to make a append and append for the given id is not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

in my code i using the append function to get values by ajax call:

```
type: 'POST',
        url: 'include/LocationService.php?run=getDistrictBoundries',
        data: {
            level : $('#level').val(),
            state : $('#stateId').val()
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#distvalue').html('');
            var districts = response.d;
            $.each(districts, function (index, district) {
                $('#distvalue').append('<option value="'+ district.geo_id+'">'+district.dist_name+'</option>');
                console.log("districtname"+districts);
            });
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#error_msg").val(textStatus);
        }
```

but in the above code:

```
$('#distvalue').append('<option value="'+ district.geo_id+'">'+district.dist_name+'</option>');
```

is not working.

so i need to get this ajax call values.how it possible?

Comment: What isn't working? What is your `console.log` statement printing? Try using `console.log("Current district: " + district);`

Answer (score 1):

in success function try this

```
var districts = response.d;
$('#distvalue').empty();

$.each(districts, function (key, data) {
  $('#distvalue').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",key).text(data));
});
```

make sure your data format was right by check json validator site, if valid should work

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting in the html for a select.  without it, the option values won't display.

Change your success function like this:

```
    success: function (response) {
        $('#distvalue').html('');
        $('#distvalue').append('<select>');

        var districts = response.d;
        $.each(districts, function (index, district) {
            $('#distvalue select').append('<option value="'+ district.geo_id+'">'+district.dist_name+'</option>');
            console.log("districtname"+districts);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $('#distvalue').append($('<option value="'+ district.geo_id+'">'+district.dist_name+'</option>'));
```